# Seat belt detection using hough transform

Tags: image-processing

I want to detect the seat belt is fasten or not. I have used the below step.

1. color segmentation
2. image bluring
3. edge detection
4. morphological transform
5. hough problabstic
6. angular filtering

Right now i am not able to extract the feature from from image which is returned by morphological transform. I am attaching the output which is returned by morpgological transform. Any help will be appreciated.

```py
img = cv2.imread('belt1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#linek = np.zeros((11,11),dtype=np.uint8)
#linek[5,...]=1
#x=cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, linek ,iterations=1)
#gray-=x

#kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
#gray = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
#gray = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)

kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size),0)

low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, low_threshold, high_threshold)

edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 80  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 100  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 40  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments
line_image = np.copy(img) * 0  # creating a blank to draw lines on

# Run Hough on edge detected image
# Output "lines" is an array containing endpoints of detected line segments
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),
                    min_line_length, max_line_gap)
```

here i am not able to extract feature:

[image]

Comment: By extracting this edge map, you discarded important information and it has become vritually impossible to find the belt in this mess. Consider image segmentation instead.

Comment: but without using edge map how we can extract the line..could you suggest some better way ?

Comment: I just did I think.